# how to get rid of zeros in PKCS7Padding

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to remove the zeros from the padding. I would like to remove the zeros without having to use a for loop, so how would I remove the zeros from the padding?

Here is the SymmetricPaddingExample.java code:

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
public class SimpleSymmetricPaddingExample{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String s = "HelloWorld";
    byte[] input = s.getBytes();

    byte[] keyBytes = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,
                          0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e, 0x0f,
                          0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17};

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    System.out.println("input: " + new String(input));

    //encryption
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0 , input.length, cipherText, 0);

    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);

    System.out.println("encrypted: " + new String(cipherText));

    //Decryption
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(cipherText.length)];

    int ptLength = cipher.update(cipherText, 0, ctLength, plainText, 0);

    ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
    System.out.println("decrypted: " + new String(plainText));
}

}
```

Comment: No for loop, seriously? Then use a while loop. What zeros are you talking about? There is no zero padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a regular expression.

```
String s = "somethingwithzeros0";
s.replaceAll("0*","");
```

or you can use this regex to filter the zeros on the end of the string:

```
s.replaceAll("0*$","");
```

Comment: I found another way, on the line with byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)]; , do this instead:  byte[] plainText = new byte[input.length];

Answer (score 1):

PKCS7 padding does not add zeros.  It adds, `0x01`, `0x0202` or `0x030303` etc.  The padding will be automatically removed by the decryption method before you see it.

Your extra zeros seem to be extra bytes left over at the end of your output array.  Your cypher text length will include the length of the padding, which will be removed automatically during decryption.  The decrypted plaintext will only partly fill your `plainText[]` array, leaving the zero bytes over at the end.  If you size the array correctly the additional zeros will disappear.